# Is there an algorithm for generating non comparable boolean vectors?

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, boolean-algebra

First some context:

1. A Boolean Network of $n$ components is a function $f$ from the set $\{0,1\}^n$ (set of vectors of $n$ components whose values are 0 or 1) to itself.
2. The dynamical behavior of a Boolean Network $f$ is given by the iteration of the function itself, i.e. for all $x(t)\in \{0,1\}^n$, $x(t+1) = f(x(t))$. Since the set $\{0,1\}^n$ is finite, this can be represented by a finite graph $G_I(f)$, what is usually called the "dynamic" of the Boolean network. A directed cycle of $G_I(f)$ that involves more than one vertex is called a **limit cycle**.
3. Given a Boolean Network $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$, $f(x) = (f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x))$,  we define the *interaction graph* $G(f)$ whose vertex are $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and there is an arc from $i$ to $j$ iff $f_j$ depends on the variable in the component $i$.
4. Given two Boolean vectors $x$ and $y$, we say that $x\leq y$ if $x_i\leq y_i$ for all $i = 1,\ldots,n$. A Boolean network $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is monotonic if for all $x$, $y \in\{0,1\}^n$, if $x\leq y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$.
5. We say that a Boolean Network $f$ is bijective if $f$ is a bijective function, i.e. $f$ is a bijection from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^n$.

I am trying to understand the relationship between lengths of limit cycles and cycles on the interaction graph of a Boolean Network. I know that bijective monotonic Boolean networks have interaction graphs composed of disjoint directed cycles, and that every limit cycle (directed cycle on the dynamic of the network) is a sequence of noncomparable Boolean vectors. The first natural question that i want to answer is: Given $S$ a sequence of noncomparable Boolean vectors, does there exists a bijective monotonic Boolean network $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ such that $S$ is a limit cycle of $f$? (That's not the question of the post)

In that sense, it will be useful to have an algorithm to generate a sequence of noncomparable Boolean vectors. Does there exists an algorithm for that?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Given two Boolean vectors $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, we say that $x$ and $y$ are $\textbf{non-comparable}$ if it's not true that $x_i\leq y_i$ (or $x_i\geq y_i$) for all $i = 1,\ldots n$.

Comment: Can you give a self-contained definition of your terms?  What is a Boolean network?  What is a bijective monotonic Boolean network?  What is the interaction network of a Boolean network?  What is a "limit cycle"?  What is the "dynamic" of a network?  Please ask only one question per post.  I see two questions in your post.  You can ask them separately, in two separate posts.

Comment: The more common term is *antichain*.

Comment: I've made some changes in the post. If it's possible i want to find a determinstic algorithm that generates an antichain of Boolean vectors. It will be useful for studying the patterns behind the connection between the two graphs associated with the Boolean network. I apologize if I don't use the standard nomenclature,  since English is not my first language.

Comment: You state you want to generate **a** sequence of noncomparable Boolean vectors. But that is trivial if no constraints are given (for example, take the empty sequence). I guess you want something else? Perhaps you want to enumerate *all* such antichains? i.e. enumerate [M(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) such sequences.

Comment: Yes, that would be a useful formulation. To be precise, given an integer $k$, i need an antichain of length $k$, build from different non comparable vectors of $\{0,1\}^n$

Comment: All vectors of weight $w$ form an antichain for all $w$. Sperner proved that taking $w = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ gives the largest possible antichain.